# Math domain error from Scipy minimize SLSQP constrained optimization

Tags: optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to minimize the function

20A + 40B subject to 120 = 100sqrt(A) + 150sqrt(B)

I wrote the following code and used it with other functions and it worked.  But this time it doesn't with math.sqrt.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np


def U(args):  
    A, B = args
    return 20*A+40*B 

def constraint(args):
    A, B = args
    return  120-100*sqrt(A)-150*sqrt(B)

con = {'type':'eq','fun':constraint}  
result1 = minimize(U, x0 = [0.1, 0.1], method='SLSQP', constraints=con)
print(f'Optimal_A is {result1.x[0]:.2f} and optimal_B is {result1.x[1]:.2f}')
```

I was able to solve this correctly using np.sqrt instead of math.sqrt.  What's going on here?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven’t tried your example, but is it possible that SLSQP is stepping into negative values for A or B? Since the constraint takes the square root of them, I’d suggest putting bounds on A and B to be non-negative.